# Adding item to a list nested in a set

Tags: python, data-structures

I want to add items to a list which is nested in a dictionary (as key-value pair).

I have tried subscribing the dictionary with the desired key and then using the `append()` and `add()` method. I now can assign a new list to the dictionary for a specific key using `dictionary[key] = [item]`. But I need something like this-

```py
G = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'],
     'B': ['C', 'F']}
```

The code I am using right now is-

```py
G = {}
G['A'].append('B')
```

It gives me the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'A'
```

I know how to declare this. But I need help in accessing and appending to the nested list for a specific key of the dictionary.

Comment: Can you please provide [mcve]?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have added the reproducible example to the question.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense at all. What is graph? what is cameFrom? What is curr?

Comment: It gives you an error because dictionary G is empty!

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma So, I have to add the first item by subscripting?

Comment: You can add it like this. ``` G['A']=['B','C','D']```

Comment: @KartikeyaSharma I misinterpreted the ```append()``` method that it will initiate as well as append. Is there any built-in way to do this?

Comment: To append something you need to have a list in place before that's why it won't append. Also I don't really understand your question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the list. Say you are accessing the list for key 'A':

```
lis=G['A']
```

Appending to the list (Say you want to append 'E' to the lis):

```
G['A'].append('E')
```